# How to modify my T-SQL UPDATE query by adding a CONDITIONAL clause?

Tags: sql-server, sql-update

I'm using SQL Server 2014 and I have an UPDATE query that runs on a table called "ResStayDate" (extract shown below):

```
ID      StayDate        RateAmount
-----------------------------------
256     2015-11-28      248.00
256     2015-11-29      248.00
256     2015-11-30      248.00
256     2015-12-01        0.00
256     2015-12-02        0.00
256     2015-12-03        0.00
```

I need to update the RateAmount column and my UPDATE query is as follows:

```
USE MyDatabase

UPDATE ResStayDate
SET RateAmount = CASE ResID
                    WHEN 256 THEN 155.00
                    ELSE RateAmount
                 END
```

My problem is that if I run this query "as is", it will update ALL the rows with 155.00. I need to update only those rows where the `StayDate` is in December 2015.

Output should be like this:

```
     ID      StayDate      RateAmount
    ---------------------------------
    256     2015-11-28      248.00
    256     2015-11-29      248.00
    256     2015-11-30      248.00
    256     2015-12-01      155.00
    256     2015-12-02      155.00
    256     2015-12-03      155.00
```

How do I modify my query so that it updates only that part of the `ResStayDate` table?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you specifically only want to affect the records in December, use the DATEPART function:

```
USE MyDatabase

UPDATE ResStayDate

SET RateAmount = CASE WHEN ResID = 256 and DATEPART(MONTH,StayDate) = 12 THEN 155.00

ELSE RateAmount

END
```

Comment: Your solution works fine. However, I have a small question: how do I handle a situation where I need to update a list of ResID? Say, I need to update three ResID (256,289,292) at a go, with each ResID having a different DATEPART? Do I need to re-write the whole code 3 times?

Comment: You will have to re-write the code 3 times: UPDATE ResStayDate SET RateAmount = CASE WHEN ResID = 256 and DATEPART(MONTH,StayDate) = 12 THEN 155.00 WHEN ResID = 289 and DATEPART(MONTH,StayDate) = 7 THEN 155.00 WHEN ResID = 292 and DATEPART(MONTH,StayDate) = 1 THEN 155.00 ELSE RateAmount END a bit like a switch statement

Answer (score 1):

```
UPDATE ResStayDate
SET RateAmount = 155
WHERE ID=256 and StayDate between '2015-12-1' and '2015-12-31'
```

This restricts your update to those records where the above mentioned conditions apply. SQL is fairly easy to read that way - not much explanation needed ;-).

**Edit**

I read your time-restriction only after I posted my first version ...

Comment: How does this address the condition "StayDate is in December 2015."